# Can't access parent page after reloading iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

To get access to the parent website from within an iframe, I use "parent.document". Here is an example:

```
$('.my-plugin', parent.document).addClass('is-active');
```

This works perfectly fine.

However, if I reload the iframe, it doesn't work anymore. The script loads, but fails whenever I run any "parent.document"-code, with this error in DevTools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (VM28598 app.js:720)
```

From what I can see in DevTools, jQuery is loading on every reload from the iframe, and my guess is that some variables/triggers is still active after the first load? It looks like this in DevTools:

```
Script: jquery-3.5.1.min.js Initaiator: app.js:663 //after first load
Script: jquery-3.5.1.min.js Initiator: VM28598 app.js:663 //after second load, etc
```

Comment: This issue is most likely due to the referrer being lost when you manually refresh the child iframe, this controls the accessibility restrictions on the content. There's no workaround for that. If you need to update content within the iframe you'll need to use AJAX to avoid the need to reload the page (and by proxy lose the referrer header)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there a reference/search phrase on this, so I can search for any solutions? I don't have control over the parent or child iframe (only a script within the iframe), so unfortunately I don't think what you suggest is possible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by unbinding the click listeners:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < parentUnbindOnRefresh.length; i++) {
    $(document).off('click', parentUnbindOnRefresh[i]);
  }
});
```

Be sure to add all your button selectors in a array, e.g:

```
parentUnbindOnRefresh = ['.back-button', '.bar-open', '.type-color'];
```